# Handling Future[WSResponse] to find success or error state

Tags: scala, playframework

In Scala I have a call to service in controller which is returning me  `Future[WSResponse]`. I want to make sure service is returning valid result so send `Ok(..)` otherwise send `BadRequest(...)`. I don't think I can use `map`. Any other suggestion?

```
def someWork = Action.async(parse.xml) { request =>
  val result:Future[WSResponse] =  someService.processData(request.body.toString())
  //Need to send back Ok or BadRequest Message 
}
```

**EDIT**
Solution from @alextsc is working fine. Now moving to test my existing test is failing. It is getting 400 instead of 200.

```
test("should post something") {
  val requestBody = <value>{UUID.randomUUID}</value>
  val mockResponse = mock[WSResponse]
  val expectedResponse: Future[WSResponse] = Future.successful(mockResponse)
  val request = FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "/posthere").withXmlBody(requestBody)

  when(mockResponse.body).thenReturn("SOME_RESPONSE")
  when(someService.processData(any[String])).thenReturn(expectedResponse)

  val response: Future[Result] = call(controller.someWork , request)

  whenReady(response) { response =>
    assert(response.header.status == 200)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track and yes, you can use `map`.

Since you're using Action.async already and your service returns a future as it stands all you need to do is map that future to a Future[Result] so Play can handle it:

```
def someWork = Action.async(parse.xml) { request =>
  someService.processData(request.body.toString()).map {
    // Assuming status 200 (OK) is a valid result for you.
    case resp : WSResponse if resp.getStatus == 200 => Ok(...)
    case _ => BadRequest(...)
  }
}
```

*(I note that your service returns `WSResponse` (from the play ws java library) and not `play.api.libs.ws.Response` (the scala version of it), hence `getStatus` and not just `status`)*

Comment: My test are breaking as I am getting 400 instead of 200. Am I doing anything wrong? OP edited with test.

Comment: @αƞjiβ You never set the mocked WSResponses status code, so it defaults to 0. Now the mapping above maps to Ok **only if the status is 200**. In all other cases (including status 0) it defaults to BadRequest.